# Django model loses its relationship ForeignKey while form is saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a databse of Customers and Treatments, with each Customer can have multiple treatments.
The problem is that a Treatment loses its Customer value in the DB, and instead of the id of the customer the value is simply NULL.

this happens in the following code:

```
def get_treatment(request, treatment_id):
    customer = Treatment.objects.get(id=treatment_id).customer
    if request.POST:
        form = TreatmentForm(request.POST, instance=Treatment.objects.get(id=treatment_id))
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() #***This is where it happens***
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = TreatmentForm(instance=Treatment.objects.get(id=treatment_id))

    return render_to_response('new_treatment.html',
                      {"form"               : form,
                       "customer_name"        : customer, 
                       },
                      RequestContext(request))
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

```
class TreatmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Treatment
        fields = "__all__"

    BOOL_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'has'),
        (False, 'none')
    )

    customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), required=False)

    # Looking inspections
    skin_hue_finding = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinHue.objects.all(), initial=0)
    skin_hue_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    skin_hue_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    skin_color_finding = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinColor.objects.all(), initial=0)
    skin_color_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    skin_color_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    pores_finding = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=Pores.objects.all(), initial=0)
    pores_area = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=GlobalArea.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(renderer=HorizontalCheckboxRenderer), required=False)
    pores_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    comdones_finding = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES))
    comdones_area = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=GlobalArea.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(renderer=HorizontalCheckboxRenderer), required=False)
    comdones_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    wrinkles_finding = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    wrinkles_area = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=WrinklesArea.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(renderer=HorizontalCheckboxRenderer), required=False)
    wrinkles_mimics = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    wrinkles_age = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    wrinkles_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    # Touching
    muscle_tonus = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=MuscleTonus.objects.all(), initial=0)
    skin_torgor = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinTorgor.objects.all(), initial=0)
    skin_thinkness = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinThickness.objects.all(), initial=0)
    skin_touch = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinTouch.objects.all(), initial=0)

    # Skin Problems
    papules = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    papules_area = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinProblemAreas.objects.all(), required=False, initial=0)
    papules_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    postules = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    postules_area = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinProblemAreas.objects.all(), required=False, initial=0)
    postules_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    scars = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    scars_area = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=SkinProblemAreas.objects.all(), required=False, initial=0)
    scars_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    malium = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    malium_area = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), queryset=MaliumAreas.objects.all(), required=False)
    malium_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    pigmentation = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    pigmentation_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    pigmentation_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    nebuses = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    nebuses_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    nebuses_comments_color = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    nebuses_comments_hair = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    macules = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    macules_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    macules_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    hypermia = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    hypermia_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    hypermia_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    coproz = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    coproz_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    coproz_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    hersotism = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    hersotism_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    hersotism_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    other_problems = forms.NullBooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, choices=BOOL_CHOICES), required=True)
    other_problems_area = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    other_problems_comments = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    skin_diagnosis = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DiagnosisCategory.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(renderer=HorizontalCheckboxRenderer), required=True)
    diagnosis_comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':55}), max_length=200, required=False)

    treatment_purpose = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':55}), max_length=200)
    customer_guidance = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), max_length=200, required=False)
    customer_recommendations = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), max_length=200, required=False)

    next_treatment_date = forms.DateField(required=True, input_formats=["%d-%m-%Y"], widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'))
    next_treatment_comments = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), max_length=200, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreatmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["next_treatment_date"].widget.attrs["class"] = "datepicker"

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TreatmentForm, self).clean()
        validation_dict = {}
        data = self.cleaned_data

        if data.get("comdones_finding") == True and len(data.get("comdones_area")) == 0:
            validation_dict["comdones_area"] = ["This field is required",]

        # Check Boolean fields
        if data.get("comdones_finding") is None:
            validation_dict["comdones_finding"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("wrinkles_finding") is None:
            validation_dict["wrinkles_finding"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("papules") is None:
            validation_dict["papules"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("postules") is None:
            validation_dict["postules"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("scars") is None:
            validation_dict["scars"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("malium") is None:
            validation_dict["malium"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("pigmentation") is None:
            validation_dict["pigmentation"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("nebuses") is None:
            validation_dict["nebuses"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("macules") is None:
            validation_dict["macules"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("hypermia") is None:
            validation_dict["hypermia"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("coproz") is None:
            validation_dict["coproz"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("hersotism") is None:
            validation_dict["hersotism"] = ["This field is required",]
        if data.get("other_problems") is None:
            validation_dict["other_problems"] = ["This field is required",]

        if validation_dict:
            raise forms.ValidationError(validation_dict)    

        return data
```

Comment: Please show the `TreatmentForm`

Comment: TreatmentForm was added

Comment: Is the customer definitely selected when you submit the form? You have `required=False` which means it's ok to set the `customer` to `None`. Do you still get the problem if you remove the `customer = forms.ModelChoiceField()` from the form, and let Django render it automatically?

Comment: Thank you, but I have made it not required in the first place because I don't want the person to modify the client of the treatment, and therefore it is impossible to change the client of the treatment in the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not submitting a value for the customer when you post the form. Blank is a valid value because you have `required=False`. Therefore Django sets customer to `None` when the form is saved.

If you don't want the `customer` field to be editable, then you should not include it in the form at all. You could do this using `exclude`.

```
class TreatmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Treatment
        exclude = ['customer']
```

Using `exclude` can be slightly dangerous. There's a risk that you add a private field to the model in future, and it gets automatically added to the form because you forgot to add it to `exclude`. You could set `fields` instead, and leave `customer` out.

```
class TreatmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Treatment
        fields = ['skin_hue_finding', 'skin_hue_area', ... <all other fields>]
```

However you might not want to do that in this case, because you have many many fields.

Comment: Thank you, but that partly solved my issue,
It fixed the issue of when I wanted to edit an existing treatment (instance of a treatment is already exists), but not when I want to add a new treatment.
Is there a way of setting a conditional exclude field, if an instance is already exists?

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, so you would be better to ask a new question. Rather than setting a conditional, I think you would be better to have two separate forms with different values for `fields` or `excludes`. To prevent duplication, one form could inherit the other, or they could both inherit from a base class.